# Can I ask questions about software analysis as well?

Tags: discussion, support, questions

I am a programmer that's pushed into analysing some project (without proper guidance!) and there are frequently some questions popping in my head which I can't find the answer to on the net. Would it be a problem if these were asked on stackoverflow?

**Example:**
I am designing this project for a company that sort of manages a list of Members (institutes, associations, universities, ...). Each member has a list of staffmembers. Now I was wondering how you ought to design the function (job) for each staffmember. Each staffmember can have more than one function (e.g. Rector and Professor). The tricky part is that a staffmember of member A could also be a staffmember of member B.

You don't have to answer to the question in the example here, just if stuff like this can be posted on Stackoverflow or not.

Comment: Can you give us an example of the kind of question you're thinking of?

Comment: Post an example here and we will tell you. For now it sounds like: yes.

Comment: updated the question with an example as requested

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

Analysis is part of software construction, and it is implied in the *programming related* mantra. For sure, analysis is programming related.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to find out. Post the question on SO. If it is acceptable and interesting it will get answers. If some people there find it unacceptable, it may get closed. But nobody here on Meta (except the SO moderators) has the power, knowledge or 
ability to decide or guarantee your question's fate in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely questions that deal with software and algorithm design are appropriate on SO.